# Why am I not able to store bash output to shell?

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

…code setting array ids, etc…

for i in "${!ids[@]}" ; do
      echo "#${ids[i]}_${pos[i]}_${wild[i]}_${sub[i]}"
      curl -sS "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"${ids[i]}".fasta";
done |
sed '/^>/ d' |
sed -r 's/[#]+/>/g' |
perl -npe 'chomp if ($.!=1 && !s/^>/\n>/)' > $id.pph.fasta
```

However the results will not store in the file. I can output the result to the terminal and store in file by doing:

```
./myscript > result.txt
```

However I want to do this within the script and output to file outside the loop.

Comment: You're writing to `$id.pph.fasta`. What is `$id`?

Comment: It looks like `$id` is undefined in your script, in which case the output of your pipeline would be going to `.pph.fasta` (a hidden file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
exec 1>result.txt
```

to the top of the script, and all output will be redirected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in ${!ids[*]}
do
  echo ">${ids[i]}_${pos[i]}_${wild[i]}_${sub[i]}"
  curl -Ss www.uniprot.org/uniprot/${ids[i]}.fasta
done |
awk '
/>/ {if (z++) printf RS; print; printf RS; getline; next}
1
END {printf RS}
' ORS= > $id.pph.fasta
```